# Why does my Minidlna server not work

Tags: media, mediaserver, dlna, minidlna

I installed `minidlna` to play local media files over my home network. I symlinked my `~/Videos/` folder to `/var/lib/minidlna/Videos`, and DLNA peers on the network can see what files are available, but whenever a peer attempts to play a file, it fails, saying that it cannot connect to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `minidlna` is configured to not follow symlinks.

To allow `minidlna` to follow symlinks, edit `/etc/minidlna.conf` and add the line `wide_links=yes` to the end of the file.

If your `/etc/minidlna.conf` has a line that says `wide_links=no`, you will need to remove or comment out this line (by adding a `#` to the beginning of the line).